# How to model the ascent and descent of a high altitude (stratospheric) balloon?

Tags: ideal-gas

I'm trying to create a MATLAB script that will plot the ascent, float, and descent of a high altitude balloon over time. The balloon should ascend to a pre-determined altitude, float around for a few hours, and will have the ability to release air as needed for a controlled descent (the balloon will not burst). I know velocity equations have sqaure roots, but how will I get around taking the square root of a negative when I want the balloon to descend?

Thanks.

Comment: How much of the physics are you trying to model? A high altitude balloon is typically flaccid when launched, expanding as the air pressure drops. As it changes shape, the drag factor changes. The temperature of the air will further affect its properties. I am not sure what equation you are working with that has a square root of velocity. Can you show the equations you are trying to implement?

Answer (score 0):

Work with absolute value. You can always define $v>0$ means up for $t<t_{float}$ and $v<0$ means down for $t>t_{float}$